# Using awk, remove lines with duplicate pair of columns in different indexes

Tags: awk

Given the following two lines:

**foo1** **foo2** foo3 foo4

foo3 foo4 **foo1** **foo2**

Line 2 is a duplicate as its pair of columns 1 and 2 are equal to columns 3 and 4 in line 1.

What's the shortest way to remove the second line using awk?

Comment: If line two was `foo4 foo3 foo1 foo2` should be removed?

Comment: No it shouldn't. However, assume that the two pair of column values 1 & 2 and 3 & 4 remain constant, just their order is swapped.

Comment: @all I appreciate if you motivate your downvote. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work , but make a check on your own:

```
cat <<EOF >file1
foo1 foo2 foo3 foo4 
foo3 foo4 foo1 foo2
foo2 foo1 foo3 foo4
fooA fooB fooC fooD
fooC fooD fooA fooB
fooD fooC fooA fooB
fooD fooB fooC fooA
EOF
awk '!f1[$1$2$3$4]++ && !f1[$3$4$1$2]++' file1
#Output
foo1 foo2 foo3 foo4 
foo2 foo1 foo3 foo4
fooA fooB fooC fooD
fooD fooC fooA fooB
fooD fooB fooC fooA
```

Edit:
As pointed out on comments, to avoid possibly unwanted concatenating of the fields and avoid confusion between `foob ar` and `foo bar` fields, is better to use the field separator FS (in whatever value this FS has been set - space by default) as part of the array indeces :

```
awk '!f1[$1FS$2FS$3FS$4]++ && !f1[$3FS$4FS$1FS$2]++' file1
```

Comment: Thank you George! Indeed now that I look at it, it was simple :). Thank you again for the input.

Comment: @faber I am glad that this worked. You can wait to get more or better answers and then you can mark the answer that worked best for you as a solution in your question by pressing the green tick

Comment: without separator between fields it may give false positives, e.g. `foo tole` vs `foot ole`

Comment: @karafka good point, added a comma and we are good to go:

awk '!a[$1,$2,$3,$4]++ && !a[$3,$4,$1,$2]++'

Thank you

Comment: @faber in my awk, the use of comma makes no difference - is the same as not using comma. To overcome the point of Karafka is better to apply something like `a[$1FS$2FS$3FS$4]`

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou using the subscript separator (`,`) does make a difference in **every** awk you must just not have a case where it matters in your sample input. Since it requires more code and could be a regexp instead of a string (e.g. with input like `ax{2}bxxc` and FS `x{2}`, the FS value `x{2}` would actually be present in $1 which would be bad for this case), using `FS` is only for the case where you have to build the index outside of it's use in the array. `,` > `FS` > `OFS` for array subscript separators.

Comment: @faber My solution should work with your updated data, did you check it?

Answer (score 2):

Using 1 array element per combination instead of 2 (matters for huge files):

```
$ awk '{r=$3FS$4FS$1FS$2} !seen[$0>r?$0:r]++' file
foo1 foo2 foo3 foo4
```

The above assumes you don't have any leading/trailing/intermediate blanks and your FS is a simple string like the default value is.

Comment: Thank you Ed for your valuable solution. It also works with the other scenario I added in my question, as the lines in question are not removed.

Comment: Is `$0>r` works for any type of data i.e alpha numeric fields? I would like to check it...

Comment: @George Yes it can work also with strings (Ed's solution actually introduced it to me).

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou yes, since neither `r` nor `$0` look like a number awk will do a string comparison even if all fields are digits and as long as it always comes up with the same result for the `>` comparison nothing else matters anyway.