# Data manipulation in linux

Tags: linux, csv, awk, sed

I am trying to filter or remove some lines in a text file based on some criteria (tried with awk, but no success).
I have a file that contains some columns separated by a comma `,`. An example of such a file is:

```
source,destination
192.168.1.2,8.8.8.8
8.8.8.8,192.168.1.2
```

I am interested to remove or filter out those lines where the information is the same.

so if the file contains the reversed source destination:

```
192.168.1.2,8.8.8.8
8.8.8.8,192.168.1.2
```

then only show one of the lines, not both.

Comment: Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Please see the [ask] help page and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) blog post by Jon Skeet.

Comment: There might be a better duplicate arround. But in the end the solution is the same: `awk '{r=$2 FS $1} !seen[$0>r?$0:r]++' file` (Cfr.  [Ed Morton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44092742/8344060))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this but be careful if the file is huge as it keeps the values in memory.

```
awk -F, '!($1 FS $2 in dup){dup[$1 FS $2]=dup[$2 FS $1]; print}' <file>
```

Same idea :

```
awk -F, '!(($1 FS $2 in dup)||($2 FS $1 in dup)){dup[$1 FS $2]; print}' <file>
```

Comment: The file is around 10k or 20k lines.

Comment: Well then it should be ok unless you have no RAM at all ^^

Comment: Seems to work well, hank you for your support!

Comment: This is an unsafe solution: Imagine the lines: `xxx.xxx.xxx.xx,ayy.yyy.yyy.yyy` and `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxa,yy.yyy.yyy.yyy`, both different but only one will be shown.

Comment: @kvantour fixed, thanks for pointing that