# Remove the lines from data-set if two value preset in one row are repeated in another rows of the data-set

Tags: perl, awk

I have a dataset of two columns. Suppose one row of the data contains values

```
"School"    "University"
```

if same values are present in different rows either in same format or opposite format(vice-versa) like

```
"University"  "School"
```

I want to retain only single row out of these two.

Input Example Data:

```
"School"       "University"
"University"   "School"
"Class"        "Room"
"WeekDay"      "Weekend"
```

Expected Output:

```
"School"       "University"
"Class"        "Room"
"WeekDay"      "Weekend"
```

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Data manipulation in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56446606/data-manipulation-in-linux)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similar to Jotne answer but using a comparison to produce the key with fields always in the same order and using the quote as delimiter:

```
awk -F\" '!a[$2 < $4 ? $2FS$4 : $4FS$2]++' file
```

This way the result doesn't depend of eventual spaces inside quoted parts.

Comment: Nice solution to the problem.

Comment: This is the idiomatic approach but the array is usually named `seen[]`, e.g. `awk '!seen[$1 > $2 ? $1 FS $2 : $2 FS $1]++' file`

Answer (score 0):

Try this Perl script:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;

my $fn = 'data.txt';
open ( my $fh, '<', $fn ) or die "Could not open file '$fn': $!";
my %data;
while (my $line = <$fh>) {
    chomp $line;
    my ($col1, $col2) = $line =~ /^\s+"([^"]*)"\s+"([^"]*)"/;
    next if $data{$col1.$col2}++;
    next if ($col1 ne $col2 ) && $data{$col2.$col1}++;
    say $line;
}
close $fh;
```

Answer (score 0):

This may work:

```
cat file
"School" "University"
"University" "School"
"Class" "Room"
"WeekDay" "Weekend"

awk '!a[$1FS$2]++ && !a[$2FS$1]++' file
"School" "University"
"Class" "Room"
"WeekDay" "Weekend"
```

It will also remove blank lines

A variation of the same solution:

```
awk '!(a[$1FS$2]++ || a[$2FS$1]++)' file
```

Comment: Nice one. But will not work if the columns have internal white space?

Comment: it also deleted the rows that contain same value in a particular row. like:                  
              a          a